# Current X driver

Tags: linux, xorg

How do I know, by which X driver, the X started.

Looking at configuration file or log file is not trustworthy, I guess. These files can be manipulated in one or other way post bootup.

Is there any way to find out which X driver was in charge to start the X ?

(e.g. Either it could be VIA, openchrome or VESA)

Comment: Why would you believe `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` is not trustworthy?  That requires root permissions to modify.  If someone with root permissions is running around being untrustworthy, you need to solve that as your real problem.

Comment: In my embedded OS, these files get removed once it's work done. Hence I would like to know the solution

Comment: Okay.  Might be nice if you included that kind of detail in the question, rather than having it dragged out of you in comments. ;)  Sans a nice command line solution, this is then very [XY-ish](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/212479).

Comment: What do you mean by “X driver”? The X server is typically started by either a display manager or `xinit`, but it could be started in any other way. If you actually meant drivers (such as VIA, VESA, etc.), the X server loads a number of drivers, not the other way round.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been mentioned, it's fairly straightforward to determine the kernel driver in use, but without the Xorg logs, it's a little more tricky to determine which userland X server driver is being used.

For systems that have it, `glxinfo` can be used (although that will only give you general device information, not the actual driver name).

```
glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: nouveau
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on NVE6
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.1 (Core Profile) Mesa 9.2.5
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 1.40
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 9.2.5
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
```

Another option is to check what modules Xorg has loaded (taken from [this](http://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/exgh4/how_do_i_find_out_what_my_current_x_driver_is/) thread on Reddit):

```
lsof -p $(pidof X) | grep xorg | rev | cut -f 1 -d '/' | rev
```

Answer (score 0):

`lspci -k` will show devices and modules loaded for them.
You can grep it for the specific device you are looking for, such as 'VGA'
`lspci -k|grep -A2 VGA`

Comment: This shows kernel drivers, not userspace X drivers, which is what the question is about.